# ValidateJarFile(D:\path\) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, apache, tomcat

This question is asked multiple times here but due to my little knowledge of using tomcat 7 with Eclipse IDE for J2EE Dev and Gradle as a build tool I am not able to fully utilize the help peovided by the members. Thus, this question.

**IDE:**

```
         Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.  
         Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
```

**Build tool** `Gradle 1.3`

**Server** `tomcat 7 - configured in Eclipse`

**Error trace:**

```
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:com.expedia.globalpayments.incentiverecon' did not find a matching property.
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Expedia\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_71-b14
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Office\project\workspace_2015_april\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Office\tomcat\tomcat-7
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Office\project\workspace_2015_april\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Office\tomcat\tomcat-7
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Office\project\workspace_2015_april\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Office\tomcat\tomcat-7\endorsed
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Denvironment.properties.location=D:\Office\incentiverecon\irEnvironmentProperties\environment.properties
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dir.log.dir=D:\Office\incentiverecon\irlogs
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Expedia\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Expedia\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;C:\gradle\gradle-1.3\bin;C:\Expedia\SQLServer(x86)\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Expedia\SQLServer(x86)\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Expedia\SQLServerShared\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Expedia\SQLServer(x86)\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Expedia\SQLServerShared\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin;C:\Expedia\KDiff3;.
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 378 ms
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:36 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [249] milliseconds.
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:37 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Office\project\workspace_2015_april\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\com.expedia.globalpayments.incentiverecon\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\Office\project\workspace_2015_april\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\com.expedia.globalpayments.incentiverecon\WEB-INF\classes\com\expedia\globalpayments\ir\checker\HealthCheckFilter.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:301)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:63)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:277)
    ... 32 more

Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/com.expedia.globalpayments.incentiverecon] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5687)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/com.expedia.globalpayments.incentiverecon] appears to have started a thread named [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/com.expedia.globalpayments.incentiverecon] appears to have started a thread named [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2015 9:49:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4906 ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't include a JAR with javax.servlet.Servlet as it is provided by Tomcat.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738888/how-to-use-provided-scope-for-jar-file-in-gradle-build) for details on how to mark the dependency as provided.  Conveniently enough, the top rated answer provides an example related to the Servlet API.

Tomcat is smart enough to not load this JAR and instead logs a warning, so that particular message is not what's causing your startup/deployment failure.

While you should address the warning, the `IncompatibleClassChangeError` is your main issue.  This is most likely caused by mixing different versions of Spring in the same project.  For example, some JARs from Spring 3.1 and others from 3.2.  Try running `gradle dependencies` and check that all of your Spring JARs are from the same release.